# How to know when an AbstractItemModel is finished updating in Qt Squish

Tags: python, qt, squish

I'm writing a unit test for a Qt application using the Squish framework. The squish scripting language is Python.

In order to make my test robust, I need to make sure that the GUI has completed an operation before checking the results.

In this GUI, I have a QTableView with an associated model. Certain operations will change the data in the model and the table will update. The update is sequenced internally by Qt.

My issue is that I need to know when the table has completed updating before I check to see whether it has the correct data.

I'm looking for ideas how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Squish not only views the *QTableView* GUI surface but will also access the underlying *QAbstractItemModel*. The data you see in your checks should therefore be live already.

But Qt GUIs are indeed full of asynchronous processing through timers, sometimes threads and signals. If you want to be notified on changes that are accompanied by a signal there's the [installSignalHandler()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-qtconvenience.html#qt-installSignalHandler-function) function. If you want to wait for a particular state of to appear there's the [waitFor()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#waitFor-function) function. In the case of the table you may want to use

```
 waitFor("mytable.model().rowCount() == 30")
```

for example.